# Where do you go to get an answer about why exactly a question was closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, help

My question was closed on the *English Language & Usage* site.

Where do I go to argue why it should not have been closed? I heard there is a meta for that. Yet, I could not find it.

Comment: Here: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for your help... again... link did not work first time

Comment: I put that link at your last question also, you should just have followed it. _"link did not work first time"_ I can hardly believe that, it's the same now, I still had that present at my clipboard.

Comment: _"When you downvote, please add why."_ Well, I did again, and there's a tooltip BTW.

Comment: It is hardly useful for future visitors,

Comment: Sorry, I tried to delete it, but since it has answers, the website would not let me.

Comment: The link did not work, it took me to the same site, yet it showed nothing as for questions. Possibly just my slow computer.

Comment: @TarynLambert _"Possibly just my slow computer."_ Huh?? How could even a slow computer affect were a link points to? The link works well for me, and as mentioned I am a 100% sure it's the same I provided at your former now deleted question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Dude. Really? Your link did not work. DID. NOT. WORK. So if you have a better explanation, go ahead and say it. The link got to the same website, but it said it had no questions available or something. How hard is it just to leave it at that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Every* site in the Stack Exchange network has a companion Meta site for discussing issues *with that site*, including questions about question closures.

For [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) it's https://english.meta.stackexchange.com.

You can simply put `meta` in the URL, or you can find links to it on the "help" and "site switcher" menus.

Comment: _""help" and "site switcher" "_ Is that the _"official"_ name of that navbar menu/button? If so, I didn't really know.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I dunno if those are official names, which is why I used quotes. The tooltips read "Help Center and other resources" and "A list of all 172 Stack Exchange sites".

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [@ale's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307274/186472):

For **every** stack exchange site you can find the link to it's corresponding meta site at the menu ("help" and "site switcher"):

[image]